# Only Getting Partial Sitemap via Get Request with Axios

Tags: xml, axios, fetch, sitemap

This might be the most bizarre problem I've experienced this year. I'm using Axios to fetch the XML from a sitemap. This had been working just fine for a Node process that had been working for weeks -- usually pulling around ~1500 objects. But now, out of nowhere, I'm only getting 54.

The tricky thing is that it works like normal on my local machine. The minute I deploy it to Digital Ocean, I only get 54. No errors. No warnings. Just 54 sitemap objects. Again, it works locally, and I've verified that there are a LOT more than 54 items in the sitemap when I scrape it.

Here's my code snippet -- how I'm scraping for these items:

```
let result = await axios.get('https://some-site.com/sitemap.xml');
```

Anyone know what might be going on? I'm at a complete loss.

Comment: Weird -- even when I `curl` the URL inside the DO droplet, I only get 54 items. What on earth!

Comment: But when I `curl` locally, it's all good. 1700 items. Ugh.

Comment: Time to break out Wireshark to see what's actually happening. Any exceptions in the server logs at DO?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- never heard of Wireshark. As it turns out, it may have been a caching issue. I checked it out today, and now I'm consistently getting the same number of items both locally and from DO.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, this may have been a caching issue all along. I tried it out a day later, and I got the same number of items both locally and from my DO droplet. It seems that my local machine was hitting a cached version from some time before.